# jQuery code above for loop not executed until afterwards

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a simple for loop that draws a certain number of points on a graph according to a specific algorithm. Since this loop can iterate a number of times and take quite a while, I want to display a loading symbol to the user while they wait. However, putting code before and after the for loop to show and hide the spinner element doesn't work.

I tested removing the line that hides the spinner once it's done, and I found that the spinner didn't show up at all until the for loop was finished executing.

I am using jQuery to add and remove a 'hidden' class like so (I can't use `.show()` or `.hide()` for other reasons):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var pointSize = 3;

var threePoints, firstPoint, lastPoint;

function placePoint(coords, context = ctx) {
    // place a point at the specified location on a 2d canvas
    // takes coordinates as array [x, y]
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(coords[0], coords[1], pointSize / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.fill();
}

function run(times = 1) {
    $('.spinner').removeClass('hidden');
    for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        let randPoint = threePoints[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
        let rise = (randPoint[1] - lastPoint[1]) / 2;
        let run = (randPoint[0] - lastPoint[0]) / 2;
        let newPoint = [lastPoint[0] + run, lastPoint[1] + rise];
        placePoint(newPoint);
        lastPoint = newPoint;
    }
    $('.spinner').addClass('hidden');
}

// this function just clears the screen and redraws the three main points and first point
function reset() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // clear the canvas
    lastPoint = firstPoint; // reset the last point

    // draw the first three points
    for (var i in threePoints) {
        placePoint(threePoints[i]);
    }
}

// this function also sets the width / height of the canvas and the coordinates of main three points and first point
function init() {
    let padding = pointSize;

    threePoints = [[padding, padding], [canvas.width - padding, padding], [canvas.width / 2, ((canvas.width / 2) * Math.sqrt(3)) - padding]];
    firstPoint = [canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2];

    reset();
}
```

```css
.spinner {
  border: 8px solid blue;
  border-top: 8px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
  display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas width="300" height="300" id="canvas">Canvas not supported</canvas><br>
<button onclick="init()">Initialize</button>
<button onclick="run(1000000)">Run 1 million points</button>
<button onclick="$('.spinner').toggleClass('hidden')">Toggle Spinner (to test)</button><br><br>
<div class="spinner hidden"></div>
```

I have also tried separating the loop into a function separate from the showing/hiding of the spinner, to no avail:

```
function run(times) {
    $('.spinner').removeClass('hidden');
    forLoop(times);
    $('.spinner').addClass('hidden');
}

function forLoop(number) {
    for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        // draw next point (same as above)
    }
}
```

I've even tried conditionally showing or hiding the spinner *inside* the for loop.

How can I make the code around the for loop execute as expected? Or is there another way to show/hide the spinner?

Comment: what is happening inside that loop?

Comment: just calculating the position of the next point and then drawing it on a canvas (through a separate function)

Comment: What does the element with `class="spinner"` look like?  Might be better to add a small fiddle by using the `<>` icon on the toolbar to include the sample html and related css as well. Jquery is available on the left side, the highest version is 3.3.1, but should suffice for this example.

Comment: Without a working example it'll be difficult to noodle with. Only thing that pops out is that rendering may be delayed by computationally-heavy loops/rendering (like whatever the drawing thing is drawing) but that seems sketch. May be able to test by trying a different browser or start the loop as a `setTimeout` callback as a sanity-check.

Comment: I have gotten an example to work in a snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suspected, on Chrome, at least, it's likely the rendering is stuck behind the foreground busy-loop. Putting the point calculations inside a timeout function is sufficient.

The other clue was that the ongoing rendering (`placePoint`) was *also* invisible, e.g., nothing rendered until the end, hence the need for the spinner in the first place. Putting `placePoint` behind a timeout *partially* resolves this, but there's still an initial delay, so in the end, the spinner is probably a better idea.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var pointSize = 3;

var threePoints, firstPoint, lastPoint;

function placePoint(coords, context = ctx) {
  // place a point at the specified location on a 2d canvas
  // takes coordinates as array [x, y]
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(coords[0], coords[1], pointSize / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.fill();
}

function run(times = 1) {
  $('.spinner').removeClass('hidden');

  setTimeout(() => {
    for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
      let randPoint = threePoints[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
      let rise = (randPoint[1] - lastPoint[1]) / 2;
      let run = (randPoint[0] - lastPoint[0]) / 2;
      let newPoint = [lastPoint[0] + run, lastPoint[1] + rise];
      placePoint(newPoint);
      lastPoint = newPoint;
    }
    $('.spinner').addClass('hidden');
  }, 0)
}

// this function just clears the screen and redraws the three main points and first point
function reset() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // clear the canvas
  lastPoint = firstPoint; // reset the last point

  // draw the first three points
  for (var i in threePoints) {
    placePoint(threePoints[i]);
  }
}

// this function also sets the width / height of the canvas and the coordinates of main three points and first point
function init() {
  let padding = pointSize;

  threePoints = [
    [padding, padding],
    [canvas.width - padding, padding],
    [canvas.width / 2, ((canvas.width / 2) * Math.sqrt(3)) - padding]
  ];
  firstPoint = [canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2];

  reset();
}
```

```css
.spinner {
  border: 8px solid blue;
  border-top: 8px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
  display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas width="300" height="300" id="canvas">Canvas not supported</canvas><br>
<button onclick="init()">Initialize</button>
<button onclick="run(1000000)">Run 1 million points</button>
<button onclick="$('.spinner').toggleClass('hidden')">Toggle Spinner (to test)</button><br><br>
<div class="spinner hidden"></div>
```